# Find which values are not in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Simple question, but I'm drawing a blank. Any help is appreciated.

I have a table of ids:

```
-------    
| ids |    
-------    
|  1  |    
|  5  |
|  7  |
-------
```

Except the actual table is thousands of entries long.

I have a list (`x`), not a table, of other ids, say 2, 6, 7. I need to see which ids from `x` are not in the `ids` table.

I need to get back `(2,6)`.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id IN (2,6,7) GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;
```

However, `COUNT(*)` returns count of retrieved rows only, it doesn't return 0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: put the list in a table (`x`) & `select * from x where x.id not in (select id from ids)`

Comment: I believe there is some construct in MySQL to create a temporary on-the-fly table just from values, but can't find it. Can anyone provide some info whether that is true. SQL Server has something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709464/create-an-inline-sql-table-on-the-fly-for-an-excluding-left-join

Comment: @StuartLC That would give me (1,5), I need (2,6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary table, insert the IDs that you need into it, and run a join, like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_wanted (id BIGINT);
INSERT INTO temp_wanted(id) VALUES (2),(6),(7);
SELECT id
FROM temp_wanted t
LEFT OUTER JOIN ids i ON i.id=t.id
WHERE i.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something with "NOT IN" clause:

```
select * from 
(SELECT 2 as id
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 as id
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 as id) mytable
WHERE ID not in (SELECT id FROM ids)
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fa9f/6)

Comment: see fiddle here... where is the fiddle ? :D

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff done the changes. I thought there wont be duplicates and hence used UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: @almasshaikh . . . The database goes through the effort of removing duplicates (as far as I know), regardless of whether or not there are any duplicates.