# MySql count() how many of type per month and return 0 if no records found

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a report for how many claimed=0 and how many claimed=1 per month and return 0 if no records. It took me forever and so far no luck! 
This is what I've got so far:

A short version of the table:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date_in    | claimed |   
+----+------------+---------+
| 1  | 2015-01-10 | 0       |
| 2  | 2015-01-09 | 1       |
| 3  | 2014-12-19 | 0       |
| 4  | 2014-11-07 | 0       |
| 5  | 2014-11-01 | 1       |
+----+------------+---------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT MONTH( date_in ) as date_in, COUNT( date_in ) AS total_items , claimed
    FROM item
    WHERE date_in >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    GROUP BY MONTH(date_in), claimed
```

This query gives me this result:

```
+---------+-------------+---------+
| date_in | total_items | claimed |     
+---------+-------------+---------+
| 1       | 1           | 0       |
| 2       | 1           | 0       |
| 2       | 1           | 1       |
| 5       | 4           | 0       |
| 5       | 4           | 1       |
| 6       | 479         | 0       |
| 6       | 167         | 1       |
| 7       | 729         | 0       |
| 7       | 211         | 1       |
| 8       | 790         | 0       |
| 8       | 229         | 1       |
| 9       | 307         | 0       |
| 9       | 66          | 1       |
+---------+-------------+---------+
```

But what I want is:

```
+---------+-------------+---------+
| date_in | total_items | claimed |     
+---------+-------------+---------+
| 1       | 1           | 0       |
| 1       | 0           | 1       |
| 2       | 0           | 0       |
| 2       | 0           | 1       |
| 3       | 0           | 0       |
| 3       | 0           | 1       |
| 4       | 0           | 0       |
| 4       | 0           | 1       |
| 5       | 4           | 0       |
| 5       | 4           | 1       |
| 6       | 479         | 0       |
| 6       | 167         | 1       |
| 7       | 729         | 0       |
| 7       | 211         | 1       |
| 8       | 790         | 0       |
| 8       | 229         | 1       |
| 9       | 307         | 0       |
| 9       | 66          | 1       |
| 10      | 0           | 0       |
| 10      | 0           | 1       |
| 11      | 0           | 0       |
| 11      | 0           | 1       |
| 12      | 0           | 0       |
| 12      | 0           | 1       |
+---------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: Table schema? Requirement? and how is total_items = 0 when claimed = 1. can you explain such things?

Comment: Edited mate. Claimed means if item claimed claimed=1 and if not claimed=0

Comment: It is still a lot confusing mate!. Your query logic works fine for the existing months. You want to fill-in for those months for which no entry exists? Is that what you want? And in your expected result for month 1 total_items = 0 for claimed = 1, when you have an entry in your table. It makes things more blurry. Explain in simple words if you can.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you with my explanation! The idea in simple words is: I need a query which will return how many items have been claimed and how many haven't. So I have two rows per month. First row says how many unclaimed meaning claimed=0. And second row how many claimed meaning claimed=1. Another example in month 6 i have 479 unclaimed and 167 claimed.

Comment: Did you try the one give by Olvathar?

Comment: it worked :) thanks for everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you'll find ok a solution with a result like:
date_in total_items_claimed total_items_unclaimed

```
SELECT MONTH( date_in ) as date_in,
SUM(IF(claimed, 1, 0)) AS total_items_claimed,
SUM(IF(claimed, 0, 1)) AS total_items_unclaimed
FROM item
WHERE date_in >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY MONTH(date_in)
```

Hope you like it :)
Edited:
For retrieving monts with no records you'll have to cross the table with another created for that:
As seen at [Create an inline SQL table on the fly (for an excluding left join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709464/create-an-inline-sql-table-on-the-fly-for-an-excluding-left-join) you could add a months_table:

```
SELECT 
  date_in, 
  total_items_claimed, 
  total_items_unclaimed, 
  COALESCE(total_items_claimed, 0) + COALESCE(total_items_unclaimed, 0) as total_items 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MONTH( date_in ) as date_in,
    SUM(IF(claimed, 1, 0)) AS total_items_claimed,
    SUM(IF(claimed, 0, 1)) AS total_items_unclaimed
  FROM item
  WHERE date_in >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  GROUP BY MONTH(date_in)
) as items_count LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 2 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 3 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 4 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 5 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 6 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 7 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 8 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 9 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 10 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 11 AS MONTH UNION
  SELECT 12 AS MONTH 
) as months_table on items_count.date_in = months_table.month
```

I have not tested this query, good luck! :)

Comment: I like your approach but there is still the same problem. It skips the months with no records, but I want it to contain 0 if no records.

Comment: This one is even better, but unfortunately it still skips the months with no records.

Comment: ouch, my fault, you can change subselects order or replace LEFT with RIGHT

Comment: Spot on mate! It finally worked. Just one more question. In months with no entries it returns NULL. is there any way of having 0 instead? Thanks!

Comment: function coalesce returns first not null object in a list of parameters

COALESCE(NULL_FIELD, ANOTHER_NULL_FIELD, 4) will return 4;
COALESCE(NULL_FIELD, NOT_NULL_FIELD, 4) will return value in NOT_NULL_FIELD; COALESCE(NULL_FIELD, ANOTHER_NULL_FIELD) will return null