# select statement that gives a range of dates without any table?

Tags: mysql, datetime

If I have a MySQL database with ZERO tables in it. Is there an SQL statement that can return results like:

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2017-06-01 |
| 2017-06-02 |
| 2017-06-03 |
| 2017-06-04 |
etc.... to any end date I want
+------------+
```

The reason I want this is because I want to be able to generate a table like this on the fly to help me with some queries in a different database.

Comment: There are ways to create it on the fly, but IMHO they all are "ugly". I'd just create a calendar table with all dates you need.

Comment: What's the big deal with the one-time action of creating calendar table? It only takes a couple of minutes, but will save you hours of SQL coding.

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB, you can use a [built-in `seq` table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/#usage-and-examples) to do this.  This query, for example, returns the 100 days starting at 1-Nov-2017

```
SELECT '2017-11-01' + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS sequential_day FROM seq_0_to_99 seq
```

In MySQL, you need to engage in some monkey business to get a sequence of numbers with no tables.  This ugly little query generates the numbers from zero to 15,625.

```
SELECT A.N + 5*(B.N + 5*(C.N + 5*(D.N + 5*(E.N + 5*(F.N))))) AS seq
  FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS A
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS B
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS C
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS D
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS E
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS F
```

You can use it as a subquery to generate a sequence of dates.

```
select '2017-11-01' + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS sequential_day
  from (
    SELECT A.N + 5*(B.N + 5*(C.N + 5*(D.N + 5*(E.N + 5*(F.N))))) AS seq
      FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS A
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS B
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS C
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS D
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS E
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS F
       ) AS seq
 where seq.seq <= 99
```

It's not very elegant. It fact, it's ugly. But it works fine.

Or you can make yourself a date table and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery to declare the first date and then increment it, like following:

```
SELECT  @date := DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS dates 
FROM mysql.help_relation , (
    SELECT @date:= DATE_SUB('2017-06-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) d 
    WHERE @date BETWEEN @date AND DATE_SUB('2017-06-04', INTERVAL 1 DAY
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create a loop and insert. Note I'm not keen on using "date" as a column name as it gets way too confusing in queries. Also suggest the date is used as primary key.

```
delimiter \\
## Create the calendar table.
CREATE TABLE calendar (
    cal_date date primary key
);
\\ 

## accepts a date range
CREATE PROCEDURE create_calendar(IN startdate date, IN enddate date)
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    WHILE (startdate + INTERVAL @x DAY) < enddate DO
        ## Insert another row
        INSERT INTO calendar (cal_date) VALUES (startdate + INTERVAL @x DAY);
        SET @x = @x + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
\\

## populate the calendar table with wanted range 
## nb the enddate is NOT included in the table

CALL create_calendar('2017-01-01','2017-02-01');
\\
select * from calendar;
\\
```

When you need more dates in the table, re-run the procedure with the wanted range (but those dates must not already exist in the calendar table).

Derived from How to [Create a Tally Table in MySQL](http://www.solomonson.com/content/how-create-tally-table-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it via `Stored Procedures` and `Inline Tables`

```
drop procedure if exists timer;
CREATE PROCEDURE timer()   
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    declare d date default now();
    drop table B;
    create table B (id date); 
    WHILE (d<='2017-11-23') DO
        insert into B values(d);
        set d = CURRENT_DATE()+i;
        set i = i+1;
    END WHILE;
    select * from B;
END;
```

And call this `SP` when you need such that `CALL timer();`

**NOTE** I am **not expert** in MYSQL and I depend on those answers to compose this answers (: so you can also benefit from, [compare dates in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql), [Inline tables in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709464/create-an-inline-sql-table-on-the-fly-for-an-excluding-left-join), [MySQL functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp), and also [While Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981901/mysql-insert-with-while-loop)

**Also Note** you can use `IN` parameter for a target date in the stored procedure